# Yahoo Pipe: How to merge 2 feed into 1 single line feed

Tags: regex, yahoo-pipes

### first i am sorry for my bad english :(

I want to merge 2 feed into 1 single line feed.

Example= in the 1st feed contain "iam" and then in the 2nd feed contain "handsome"
i want to merge that 2 feed into 1 single line feed, so the output feeds
will looks like this => `"iam handsome"`

i've been try to solve it many time but the output always 
looks like below

```
  "iam"       (feed 1)
  "handsome"  (feed 2)
```

Is that posible to make it right?

Any advice will be helpfull to me.

Best Regard.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to merge 2 feeds together and create a single feed the FetchFeed Source and pipe to output. Here is how http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/docs?doc=sources#FetchFeed without the FILTER option box